# requireJS and window resize

Tags: jquery, resize, requirejs

I have the following code

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var screenSize;

    screenSize = {
        isSmallScreen: function () {
            var smallScreen = $(".container-inner").width() <= 570;

            $(window).resize(function () {
                smallScreen = $(".container-inner").width() <= 570;
            });

            return smallScreen;
        }
    }
    return screenSize;
});
```

I can call screenSize.isSmallScreen(); in other files and get the returned value of smallScreen but not when I resize the window. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
$(window).on("resize", function(event) {
    // your logic here
});
```

Instead of `$(window).resize(...)`.

Comment: That dosent work either. I think the problem is smallScreen is not accessible outside of resize function...